# CoreTelephony api is not working in Guided Access Mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, guided-access

I want to show UIAlertView when Guided Access Mode is enable and  there is an incoming call but i have found that CoreTelephony api is not getting called when Guided Access Mode is enable.

How can i inform user with some information that they need to come out from Guided Access mode to receive and dial a call?

Answer (score 0):

i google it and found this, hope some help.http://appadvice.com/appnn/2012/09/new-feature-in-ios-6-how-to-use-guided-access

Comment: I know about Guided Access Mode.I wanted to know is if guided access mode is enable how i came to know that i got the miss in my current app.